# Media module and wysiwyg inserts image link rather than rendered image

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I'm using [wyswig](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) and [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) with [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module to insert images into the body field of a node.

Instead of displaying the image it displays a link to the image. Viewing source this is what is inserted:

```
<p><span class="file media-element file-default" data-file_info="%7B%22fid%22:%2213%22,%22view_mode%22:%22default%22,%22type%22:%22media%22%7D"><img alt="" class="file-icon" src="/modules/file/icons/image-x-generic.png" title="image/jpeg" /> <a href="http://dev.charm.ucsf.edu/sites/dev.charm.ucsf.edu/files/feature_MB2.jpg" type="image/jpeg; length=22001">feature_MB2.jpg</a></span></p>
```

I have "**Convert Media tags to markup** checked" and I am NOT **limiting HTML tags**. Any ideas why it's stripping out the **"["** and **"]"**?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: You should have a look at the [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module.

Comment: Have you tried `Full HTML` in field ?

Comment: What version of Media are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "stripping out" the brackets? The media button on the editor will insert JSON that describes what display mode you want to use. Then, when the node is rendered, the "Convert Media tags to markup" input filter converts that JSON to the appropriate HTML, in line with the display mode. If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should select the answer by @6c1

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this in the web admin GUI:

Configuration > Media > File Types > Image > Manage File Display > Check the "Image" box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found a solution by now, but I had the same issue and it turned out to be panels that was causing the problem.  To solve this, I went to Page Manager > My Variant > Content. I then chose the piece of content that had the image in it and in the settings changed the formatter to 'Rendered File' and chose the view mode 'Large' (it had been 'Rendered File': 'Default', which displayed the link to the image rather than the image itself). I hope this helps!